# How do I update an html table after each XML call to the server without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a mySQL table loaded with 50 rows. Each row has the necessary information to process a credit card. When the user clicks on Process Credit Cards, query the table and display each row on the page using html. Once the data has been displayed on the page a scrip would begin to process each row through the merchant account and turn the corresponding row either red for decline or green for approve without refreshing the page after each transaction. I think I need to use AJAX or jQuery to make this happen but I'm not sure I'm headed in the right direction. Here is the script to process the transactions:

```
<?php
$request = new GatewayRequest();
$response = new GatewayResponse();
$service = new GatewayService();


$request->Set(GatewayRequest::MERCHANT_ID(), "111111111111111");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::MERCHANT_PASSWORD(), "xxxxxxxxxxxx");


$time = time();
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::MERCHANT_CUSTOMER_ID(), $time . '.PHPTest');
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::MERCHANT_INVOICE_ID(), $time . '.SaleTest');



$request->Set(GatewayRequest::AMOUNT(), "9.99");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::CARDNO(), "4111111111111111");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::EXPIRE_MONTH(), "02");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::EXPIRE_YEAR(), "2010");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::CVV2(), "999");


$request->Set(GatewayRequest::CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME(), "Joe");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::CUSTOMER_LASTNAME(), "PHPTester");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::EMAIL(), "phptest@fakedomain.com");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::IPADDRESS(), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


$request->Set(GatewayRequest::BILLING_ADDRESS(), "123 Main St");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::BILLING_CITY(), "Las Vegas");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::BILLING_STATE(), "NV");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::BILLING_ZIPCODE(), "89141");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::BILLING_COUNTRY(), "US");




$request->Set(GatewayRequest::SCRUB(), "IGNORE");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::CVV2_CHECK(), "IGNORE");
$request->Set(GatewayRequest::AVS_CHECK(), "IGNORE");

$service->SetTestMode(TRUE);

if ($service->PerformPurchase($request, $response)) {
  print "Purchase succeeded\n";
  print "Response Code: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::RESPONSE_CODE()) . "\n";
  print "Reasone Code: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::REASON_CODE()) . "\n";
  print "Auth No: " . $response->Get(GatewayResponse::AUTH_NO()) . "\n";
  print "AVS: " . $response->Get(GatewayResponse::AVS_RESPONSE()) . "\n";
  print "CVV2: " . $response->Get(GatewayResponse::CVV2_CODE()) . "\n";
  print "GUID: " . $response->Get(GatewayResponse::TRANSACT_ID()) . "\n";
  print "Account: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::MERCHANT_ACCOUNT()) . "\n";
  print "Scrub: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::SCRUB_RESULTS()) . "\n";
} else {
  print "Purchase failed\n";
  print "GUID: " . $response->Get(GatewayResponse::TRANSACT_ID()) . "\n";
  print "Response Code: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::RESPONSE_CODE()) . "\n";
  print "Reasone Code: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::REASON_CODE()) . "\n";
  print "Exception: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::EXCEPTION()) . "\n";
  print "Scrub: " .
    $response->Get(GatewayResponse::SCRUB_RESULTS()) . "\n";
}

?>
```

Will this type of code work with AJAX or jQuery without being rewritten? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be made to work without being rewritten, but you've set yourself up for a lot of headaches there.  You'll probably have much better luck (and save yourself tons of time) by formatting all those print statements into an array and JSON encoding it.  Obviously javascript loves JSON.

Comment: How would I format this code in AJAX which uses Javascript? I have all the necessary pieces except how to use the above code in a Javascript function using the httpObject.open?

Comment: There's a really great tutorial here on using httpObject.open: [link](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html?page=1).  

If you JSON encode your response then the httpObject.responseText will be a javascript object.  Probably the easiest thing to do at that point would be to just access the properties of the object using dot notation. (i.e. httpObject.responseText.[your param])